# HTML Javascript Self-assessment quiz/questionnaire

Tags: javascript, html

Hi so i got a very basic JavaScript HTML quiz working, however what i want to end up with is an assessment type quiz that has lets say 15 questions based on 3 categories (e.g. Alcoholism, depression, drug abuse) e.g.

How often to you drink alcohol? 
- All the time
-  Occasionally
- Never

the player answers all 15 questions and at the end depending on how they answered the questions they get assigned a category e.g. your category is Drug Abuse etc.

I'm thinking that maybe each category has its own counter and a value is applied to each of the possible answers e.g. All the time gives a score of 3, occasionally scores a 2 etc. As the player answers the questions, the values get stored in the corresponding category and at the end the scores for each category are added up and the category with the highest score gets assigned to the player?

Any help with this would be appreciated :)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2 id="test_status"></h2>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
div#test {

     border:#000 1px solid;
     padding: 10px 40px 40px 40px;
}
</style>
```

JS:

```
    <script>
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;
var questions = [
    ["How often do you drink?", "All the time", "Often", "Never", "B"],
    ["Do you ever feel sad for no reason?", "All the time", "Often", "Never", "C"],
    ["Have you ever tried drugs", "All the time", "Often", "Never", "C"],
    ["Do you feel uneasy around people", "All the time", "Often", "Never", "C"]


];

function _(x) {

   return document.getElementById(x);

}

function renderQuestion () {

   test = _("test");
   if(pos >= questions.length) {
     test.innerHTML = "<h2>Your Category is  </h2>";
     _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
     pos = 0;
     correct = 0;
     return false;
     }



   _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+" of"+questions.length;
  question = questions[pos] [0];
  chA = questions[pos] [1];
  chB = questions[pos] [2];
  chC = questions[pos] [3];
  test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
  test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>";
  test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>";
  test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br><br>"; 
  test.innerHTML +="<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>submit Answer</button>"; 
   }

   function checkAnswer() {
     choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
     for (var i=0; i<choices.length; i++) {
     if(choices[i].checked) {
       choice = choices[i].value;
   }
   }
    if(choice == questions[pos] [4]) {
     correct++;
     }
     pos++;
     renderQuestion();
   }
   window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a programming question or is this about the logic to your questionnaire?

Comment: I'm trying to find out how i would go about coding what i mentioned above..or if anyone has a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable Javascript snippet its generated by **[TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/)**(a public GIT repository is available on this [**bucket**](https://bitbucket.org/InferOn/typescript-quiz/src)), The quiz its organized by arguments and categories; below you can see the UML diagram.

[image]

```js
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
var Categories;
(function (Categories) {
    var QuestionCategory = (function () {
        function QuestionCategory(value) {
            this.Value = value;
        }
        return QuestionCategory;
    })();
    Categories.QuestionCategory = QuestionCategory;
    var AQuestionCategory = (function (_super) {
        __extends(AQuestionCategory, _super);
        function AQuestionCategory() {
            _super.call(this, 1);
        }
        return AQuestionCategory;
    })(QuestionCategory);
    Categories.AQuestionCategory = AQuestionCategory;
    var BQuestionCategory = (function (_super) {
        __extends(BQuestionCategory, _super);
        function BQuestionCategory() {
            _super.call(this, 2);
        }
        return BQuestionCategory;
    })(QuestionCategory);
    Categories.BQuestionCategory = BQuestionCategory;
    var CQuestionCategory = (function (_super) {
        __extends(CQuestionCategory, _super);
        function CQuestionCategory() {
            _super.call(this, 3);
        }
        return CQuestionCategory;
    })(QuestionCategory);
    Categories.CQuestionCategory = CQuestionCategory;
})(Categories || (Categories = {}));
var Questions;
(function (Questions) {
    var Answer = (function () {
        function Answer(text, value) {
            this.Text = text;
            this.Value = value;
        }
        return Answer;
    })();
    Questions.Answer = Answer;
    var Question = (function () {
        function Question(text, id, category, answers) {
            this.Text = text;
            this.ID = id;
            this.Category = category;
            this.Answers = answers;
        }
        Question.prototype.Render = function () {
            var _this = this;
            var dContainer = document.createElement("div");
            var dQuestion = document.createElement("h3");
            dQuestion.innerHTML = this.Text;
            dContainer.appendChild(dQuestion);
            var dCategory = document.createElement("div");
            dCategory.innerHTML = 'Category: ' + this.Category.Value;
            dContainer.appendChild(dCategory);
            dContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            var counter = 0;
            this.Answers.forEach(function (a) {
                var __id = _this.ID + counter;
                var dRadio = document.createElement("input");
                dRadio.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
                dRadio.setAttribute('id', __id);
                dRadio.setAttribute('data-category', _this.Category.Value + '');
                dRadio.setAttribute('value', a.Value + '');
                dRadio.setAttribute('name', _this.ID);
                var dLabel = document.createElement("label");
                dLabel.innerHTML = a.Text;
                dLabel.setAttribute('For', __id);
                dContainer.appendChild(dRadio);
                dContainer.appendChild(dLabel);
                counter++;
            });
            dContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));
            return dContainer;
        };
        return Question;
    })();
    Questions.Question = Question;
    var QuestionCollection = (function () {
        function QuestionCollection(questions) {
            this.Questions = questions;
        }
        QuestionCollection.prototype.Render = function () {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            this.Questions.forEach(function (q) {
                div.appendChild(q.Render());
            });
            return div;
        };
        return QuestionCollection;
    })();
    Questions.QuestionCollection = QuestionCollection;
    var QuestionArgument = (function () {
        function QuestionArgument(name, collection) {
            this.Collection = collection;
            this.Name = name;
        }
        QuestionArgument.prototype.Render = function () {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var h1Arg = document.createElement("h1");
            h1Arg.innerHTML = this.Name;
            div.appendChild(h1Arg);
            div.appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));
            div.appendChild(this.Collection.Render());
            return div;
        };
        return QuestionArgument;
    })();
    Questions.QuestionArgument = QuestionArgument;
    var QuizManager = (function () {
        function QuizManager(hook, arguments) {
            this.Arguments = arguments;
            this.Hook = hook;
        }
        QuizManager.prototype.Render = function () {
            var _this = this;
            this.Arguments.forEach(function (arg) {
                _this.Hook.appendChild(arg.Render());
            });
            var btn = document.createElement('input');
            btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
            btn.setAttribute('value', 'Done');
            btn.onclick = function (e) {
                _this.Compute();
            };
            this.Hook.appendChild(btn);
        };
        QuizManager.prototype.Compute = function () {
            var _this = this;
            var cats = [], dxCat = [], dxCatTotValue = [];
            this.Arguments.forEach(function (arg) {
                arg.Collection.Questions.forEach(function (q) {
                    if (cats.length > 0) {
                        if (cats.indexOf(q.Category) === -1)
                            cats.push(q.Category);
                    }
                    else
                        cats.push(q.Category);
                });
            });
            cats.forEach(function (c) {
                var p = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-category =\'' + c.Value + '\']:checked');
                var tv = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                    if (parseInt(p[i]['value']) != NaN)
                        tv += parseInt(p[i]['value']);
                }
                dxCatTotValue.push({ "Cat": c.Value, "TVal": tv });
            });
            
            this.Hook.appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));
            var summariH2 = document.createElement("h2");
            summariH2.innerHTML = 'Summary';
            dxCatTotValue.sort(this.Compare);
            dxCatTotValue.forEach(function (catValue) {
                var entryDiv = document.createElement("div");
                entryDiv.innerHTML = 'Category ' + catValue['Cat'] + ': ' + catValue['TVal'];
                _this.Hook.appendChild(entryDiv);
            });
            this.Hook.appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));
        };
        QuizManager.prototype.Compare = function (a, b) {
            if (a['TVal'] > b['TVal'])
                return -1;
            if (a['TVal'] < b['TVal'])
                return 1;
            return 0;
        };
        return QuizManager;
    })();
    Questions.QuizManager = QuizManager;
})(Questions || (Questions = {}));
window.onload = function () {
    var CCat = new Categories.CQuestionCategory();
    var BCat = new Categories.BQuestionCategory();
    var ACat = new Categories.AQuestionCategory();
    var q1 = new Questions.Question('Do you eat Apples?', 'q1', CCat, [new Questions.Answer('All the time', 1), new Questions.Answer('Occasionally', 2), , new Questions.Answer('Never', 3)]);
    var q2 = new Questions.Question('Do you like Pears?', 'q2', BCat, [new Questions.Answer('Yes', 1), new Questions.Answer('No', 2)]);
    var fruitsquestions = new Questions.QuestionCollection([q1, q2]);
    var fruitsArguments = new Questions.QuestionArgument('Fruits', fruitsquestions);
    var q3 = new Questions.Question('Do you eat Onions?', 'q3', ACat, [new Questions.Answer('Yes', 1), new Questions.Answer('No', 2)]);
    var q4 = new Questions.Question('Do you like Cucumbers?', 'q4', CCat, [new Questions.Answer('All the time', 1), new Questions.Answer('Occasionally', 2), , new Questions.Answer('Never', 3)]);
    var vegetablesQuestions = new Questions.QuestionCollection([q3, q4]);
    var vegetablesArguments = new Questions.QuestionArgument('Vegetables', vegetablesQuestions);
    var quiz = new Questions.QuizManager(document.getElementById("content"), [fruitsArguments, vegetablesArguments]);
    quiz.Render();
};
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

The TypeScript source:

```
module Categories {
  export class QuestionCategory {
    Value: number;
    Text: string;

    constructor(value: number) { this.Value = value; }
  }

  export class AQuestionCategory extends QuestionCategory {
    constructor() { super(1); }
  }

  export class BQuestionCategory extends QuestionCategory {
    constructor() { super(2); }
  }

  export class CQuestionCategory extends QuestionCategory {
    constructor() { super(3); }
  }
}

module Questions {
  import QC = Categories;

  export class Answer {
    Text: string;
    Value: number;
    constructor(text: string, value: number) {
      this.Text = text;
      this.Value = value;
    }
  }
  export class Question {
    Category: QC.QuestionCategory;
    Answers: Answer[];
    Text: string;
    ID: string;

    constructor(text: string, id: string, category: QC.QuestionCategory, answers: Answer[]) {
      this.Text = text;
      this.ID = id;
      this.Category = category;
      this.Answers = answers;
    }

    Render(): HTMLElement {
      var dContainer = document.createElement("div");
      var dQuestion = document.createElement("h3")
      dQuestion.innerHTML = this.Text;
      dContainer.appendChild(dQuestion);
      var dCategory = document.createElement("div")
      dCategory.innerHTML = 'Category: ' + this.Category.Value;
      dContainer.appendChild(dCategory);
      dContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      var counter = 0;
      this.Answers.forEach(a => {
        var __id = this.ID + counter;

        var dRadio = document.createElement("input");
        dRadio.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
        dRadio.setAttribute('id', __id);
        dRadio.setAttribute('data-category', this.Category.Value + '');
        dRadio.setAttribute('value', a.Value + '');
        dRadio.setAttribute('name', this.ID);

        var dLabel = document.createElement("label");
        dLabel.innerHTML = a.Text
        dLabel.setAttribute('For', __id)
        dContainer.appendChild(dRadio);
        dContainer.appendChild(dLabel);

        counter++;
      });
      dContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));
      return dContainer;
    }
  }
  export class QuestionCollection {

    Questions: Question[];
    constructor(questions: Question[]) { this.Questions = questions; }
    Render(): HTMLElement {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      this.Questions.forEach(q => {
        div.appendChild(q.Render());

      });
      return div;
    }

  }
  export class QuestionArgument {
    Name: string;
    Collection: QuestionCollection;

    constructor(name: string, collection: QuestionCollection) {
      this.Collection = collection;
      this.Name = name;
    }

    Render(): HTMLElement {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      var h1Arg = document.createElement("h1");
      h1Arg.innerHTML = this.Name;
      div.appendChild(h1Arg);
      div.appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));
      div.appendChild(this.Collection.Render());
      return div;
    }
  }

  export class QuizManager {
    Hook: HTMLElement;
    Arguments: QuestionArgument[];
    constructor(hook: HTMLElement, arguments: QuestionArgument[]) {
      this.Arguments = arguments;
      this.Hook = hook;
    }

    Render() {
      this.Arguments.forEach(arg => {
        this.Hook.appendChild(arg.Render());

      });

      var btn = <HTMLButtonElement> document.createElement('input');
      btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
      btn.setAttribute('value', 'Done');
      btn.onclick = (e) => { this.Compute(); }
      this.Hook.appendChild(btn);
    }
    Compute() {
      var cats = [], dxCat = [], dxCatTotValue = [];

      this.Arguments.forEach(arg => {
        arg.Collection.Questions.forEach(q => {
          if (cats.length > 0) {
            if (cats.indexOf(q.Category) === -1)
              cats.push(q.Category);  
          }
          else
            cats.push(q.Category);

        });
      });
      cats.forEach(c => {
        var p = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-category =\'' + c.Value + '\']:checked');
        var tv = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
        {
          if (parseInt(p[i]['value']) != NaN)
            tv += parseInt(p[i]['value']);

        } 
        dxCatTotValue.push({ "Cat": c.Value, "TVal": tv });

      })

      //this.Hook.appendChild(btn);
      this.Hook.appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));
      var summariH2 = document.createElement("h2");
      summariH2.innerHTML = 'Summary';

      dxCatTotValue.sort(this.Compare);
      dxCatTotValue.forEach(catValue => {
        var entryDiv = document.createElement("div");
        entryDiv.innerHTML = 'Category ' + catValue['Cat'] + ': ' + catValue['TVal'];
        this.Hook.appendChild(entryDiv);  
      });

      this.Hook.appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));

    }

    Compare(a, b) {
      if (a['TVal'] > b['TVal'])
        return -1;
      if (a['TVal'] < b['TVal'])
        return 1;
      return 0;
    }
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
  var CCat = new Categories.CQuestionCategory();
  var BCat = new Categories.BQuestionCategory();
  var ACat = new Categories.AQuestionCategory();

  var q1 = new Questions.Question('Do you eat Apples?', 'q1',
    CCat,
    [new Questions.Answer('All the time', 1), new Questions.Answer('Occasionally', 2), , new Questions.Answer('Never', 3)]);
  var q2 = new Questions.Question('Do you like Pears?', 'q2',
    BCat,
    [new Questions.Answer('Yes', 1), new Questions.Answer('No', 2)]);

  var fruitsquestions = new Questions.QuestionCollection([q1, q2]);
  var fruitsArguments = new Questions.QuestionArgument('Fruits', fruitsquestions);


  var q3 = new Questions.Question('Do you eat Onions?', 'q3',
    ACat,
    [new Questions.Answer('Yes', 1), new Questions.Answer('No', 2)]);

  var q4 = new Questions.Question('Do you like Cucumbers?', 'q4',
    CCat,
    [new Questions.Answer('All the time', 1), new Questions.Answer('Occasionally', 2), , new Questions.Answer('Never', 3)]);

  var vegetablesQuestions = new Questions.QuestionCollection([q3, q4]);
  var vegetablesArguments = new Questions.QuestionArgument('Vegetables', vegetablesQuestions);

  var quiz = new Questions.QuizManager(document.getElementById("content"), [fruitsArguments, vegetablesArguments]);
  quiz.Render();

};
```

Answer (score 0):

this [quiz maker](http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/resources/quizzes/quizmcmaker.html) produces a very simple set of HTML and it's obvious where the total calculation is in order to change it.

You can simply add the numbers of questions relating to each answer, then compare to say which is largest and display the result. It gives you a choice of having radio buttons in a list for each question, or several on one line.

All the questions will display on a single page, rather than having to press Next each time which can be annoying for people doing the quiz. No CSS is needed and hardly any javascript.

Example code for a self-scoring quiz with 1 question of each type (drop-down box, short answer, multiple answers etc). The generator tool in the link above will create something similar, it's pure HTML and javascript with no external scripts to load, no jquery or dependencies.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional/EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dkj.css" type="text/css">
<title>Quiz: Sample "Think Again" Quiz</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var stuff = new Array (51) // maximum number of questions
var answered = new Array (51) // processing inhibitor for guessers
for(var i = 0; i<=50; i++){stuff[i]=0; answered[i]=0} //initialize arrays// --> </script>

</head>

<body bgcolor ="#ffff88" text="#000000" link="#000088" vlink="purple" alink="#880000" >
<a name="top"></a> 
<p align='right'><font size=-1>
Quiz created: 1999/1/31 
</font></p>


<center>
<h2><font color="#ff3333">Sample "Think Again" Quiz</font></h2></center>

<noscript>
<p><font color="#880000">
I'm sorry. This page requires that your browser be capable of running JavaScript in order to use the self-correcting feature of the quiz. 
In most browsers you can activate JavaScript using a dialog box somewhere under one of the menu bar options. If you are really using a (rare) non-JavaScript-capable browser, you will have to do without the self-grading features of this page.</font></p>
</noscript>

<p>
<b>Instructions: </b>
Answer the multiple choice questions, guessing if necessary, 
then click on the "Process Questions" button to see your 
score. The program will not reveal which questions you got wrong, only how 
many points you have. Go back and change your answers until you get them all 
right. (The message box will rejoice at that point and the page will change color in delight.)</p>

<p>
<b>Points to note: </b>

(1)&nbsp;Questions with only one possible answer are one point each. 
(2)&nbsp;Questions with <i>one or more</i> possible answers (represented by check boxes) 
give a point for each correct answer, but also subtract a point for each wrong answer! 
(3)&nbsp;The program will not attempt to score your efforts at all if 
you have not tried at least half of the questions. 
(4)&nbsp;This practice quiz is for your own use only. 
No record of your progress is kept or reported to anyone. </p>
<hr>

<form name="formzSampQuiz">

1. Fog is notorious in
<blockquote>
<input type=radio name=quest1 onClick="stuff[1]=0; answered[1]=1">New York&nbsp;
<input type=radio name=quest1 onClick="stuff[1]=0; answered[1]=1">Chicago&nbsp;
<input type=radio name=quest1 onClick="stuff[1]=1; answered[1]=1">London&nbsp;
<input type=radio name=quest1 onClick="stuff[1]=0; answered[1]=1">Los Angeles&nbsp;
<input type=radio name=quest1 checked onClick="stuff[1]=0; answered[1]=0">No Answer </blockquote>

2. Chicago is in
<blockquote>
<input type=radio name=quest2 onClick="stuff[2]=0; answered[2]=1">Montana&nbsp;
<input type=radio name=quest2 onClick="stuff[2]=0; answered[2]=1">Manitoba&nbsp;
<input type=radio name=quest2 onClick="stuff[2]=0; answered[2]=1">Missouri&nbsp;
<input type=radio name=quest2 onClick="stuff[2]=1; answered[2]=1">Illinois&nbsp;
<input type=radio name=quest2 checked onClick="stuff[2]=0; answered[2]=0">No Answer </blockquote>

3. The famous French Queen Marie Antoinette was married to
<blockquote>
<select name=quest3 size=1 onChange="figureout3()"><option selected>No Answer <option>St. Louis 
<option>Louis XVI 
<option>Louis DXLVIII 
<option>Louis Rukeyser 
<option>Louey, brother of Dewey and and Huey 
<option>John L. Louis 
</select>

<script type="text/javascript"><!-- //Pre-processor for question 3";
function figureout3() { 
if (document.formzSampQuiz.quest3.options.selectedIndex == 0)
   {stuff[3] = 0; answered[3]=0} // no answer
else if (document.formzSampQuiz.quest3.options.selectedIndex == 2)
   {stuff[3] = 1; answered[3]=1} // right answer
else {stuff[3] = 0; answered[3]=1} // wrong answer
} // end function figureout3()
//--></script>

</blockquote>

4. Compared with Elizabeth II, Elizabeth I was
<blockquote>
<input type=radio name=quest4 onClick="stuff[4]=1; answered[4]=1">earlier&nbsp;
<input type=radio name=quest4 onClick="stuff[4]=0; answered[4]=1">later&nbsp;
<input type=radio name=quest4 checked onClick="stuff[4]=0; answered[4]=0">No Answer </blockquote>

5. Which of the Following are saints?
<blockquote>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- //Script to pre-process question 5
function figureout5() {
stuff[5]=0; answered[5]=0
if(document.formzSampQuiz.q5p2.checked==true){stuff[5]--; answered[5]=1}
if(document.formzSampQuiz.q5p3.checked==true){stuff[5]++; answered[5]=1}
if(document.formzSampQuiz.q5p4.checked==true){stuff[5]++; answered[5]=1}
if(document.formzSampQuiz.q5p5.checked==true){stuff[5]--; answered[5]=1}
if(document.formzSampQuiz.q5p6.checked==true){stuff[5]--; answered[5]=1}
} //end function figure5
// --></script>
<input type=checkbox name="q5p2" onClick="figureout5()">
Jack-the-Ripper&nbsp; 
<input type=checkbox name="q5p3" onClick="figureout5()">
St. Augustine&nbsp; 
<input type=checkbox name="q5p4" onClick="figureout5()">
St. Ursula&nbsp; 
<input type=checkbox name="q5p5" onClick="figureout5()">
Adolf Hitler&nbsp; 
<input type=checkbox name="q5p6" onClick="figureout5()">
Napoleon&nbsp; 
</blockquote>

6. Which of the following is <i>not</i> one of the Seven Deadly Sins?
<blockquote>
<select name=quest6 size=1 onChange="figureout6()"><option selected>No Answer <option>pride 
<option>lust 
<option>envy 
<option>stupidity 
<option>anger 
<option>covetousness 
<option>gluttony 
<option>sloth  
</select>

<script type="text/javascript"><!-- //Pre-processor for question 6";
function figureout6() { 
if (document.formzSampQuiz.quest6.options.selectedIndex == 0)
   {stuff[6] = 0; answered[6]=0} // no answer
else if (document.formzSampQuiz.quest6.options.selectedIndex == 4)
   {stuff[6] = 1; answered[6]=1} // right answer
else {stuff[6] = 0; answered[6]=1} // wrong answer
} // end function figureout6()
//--></script>

</blockquote>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--// Processor for questions 1-6> 
function processqzSampQuiz() { 
document.bgColor='#ffff88'
 var goodguyszSampQuiz=0 // used to calculate score
var inhibitzSampQuiz=0 // used to prevent processing of partially completed forms

for (var i=1; i<=6; i++){
  goodguyszSampQuiz=goodguyszSampQuiz + stuff[i]; inhibitzSampQuiz = inhibitzSampQuiz + answered[i];
} // end for

// Prevent display of score if too few questions completed
if (inhibitzSampQuiz < 3){ 
  document.formzSampQuiz.grade.value="You must try at least 3!"
  document.formzSampQuiz.score.value= "Secret!"; 
} // end if

else {
  document.formzSampQuiz.score.value=goodguyszSampQuiz;
    if (goodguyszSampQuiz==7){
       document.formzSampQuiz.grade.value="Hooray!"
       document.bgColor="#ff9999"

    }else {document.formzSampQuiz.grade.value="Keep Trying!"}
} // end else
} // end function processqzSampQuiz()

function killall(){ //keep final scores from hanging around after reset clears form
goodguys=0; inhibitaa=0;
for (i=0; i<=50; i++){stuff[i]=0; answered[i]=0}
} // end functionl killall()
// --> </script>

<input type=button name=processor value="Process Questions" onClick=processqzSampQuiz()>&nbsp;<input type=reset value="Reset" onClick="killall(); document.bgColor='#ffff88'"> &nbsp;
<input type=text name="grade" value="Nothing!" size=25 onFocus="blur()"> &nbsp; 
Points out of 7: 
<input type=text name="score" value="Zip!" size=10 onFocus="blur()">
<br></form>

<p align='right'><font size=-1>
<a href="#top">Return to top.</a></font></p>
<hr>
<!-- You can edit this acknowledgement out if you like. -->
<p align='right'><font size=-1>
This consummately cool, pedagogically compelling, self-correcting, <br>
multiple-choice quiz was produced automatically from <br>
a text file of questions using D.K. Jordan's<br>
<a href="http://anthro.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/resources/quizzes/quizzes.html">
Think Again Quiz Maker</a> <br>
of October 31, 1998.<br>

</font></p>
</body></html>
```